# Is it safe to visit a malicious site with javascript disabled, in Linux?

Tags: security

What can happen if I visit known malicious site using Linux with javascript, java and flash disabled. Is there an attack vector that can take place regardless?

Comment: If you really want to visit the site, you could use a virtual appliance.  Basically use something like a livecd within Virtual Box or your favorite VM.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but virtual box freezes my machine for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

There still could be vulnerabilities in the browser code itself.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's look at the stack from a browser exploit level.

- **Page Download**: When you download the page, it could trace your computer, your ISP, etc. and launch a DDoS or similar on it.
- **Page Render**: The page, when rendered, can very easily be exploited with browser exploits using stuff like drive-by downloads, although most (95%) of that can be avoided by disabling Javascript. Javascript isn't the only problem though—check out [this CSS hack](http://browserspy.dk/css-exploit.php).
- **User Interaction**: Which is the hugest part. Browsers are pretty darn secure nowadays—you aren't. Just because you visit a site without any security issues in sight doesn't mean that you're out of the woods.

If you really need to visit this site, the best way is buy using Chromium in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lynx](http://www.lynxbrowser.com/) instead?  I don't see how anything malicious could get by it.